# Factorize $a^2-ab-bc\pm c^2$

Tags: factoring

I got this question in a test but it did not specify the variable with respect to which I was supposed to factorize

$$a^2-ab-bc\pm c^2$$

where it could be just $a(a-b)-c(b\pm c)$ but no common factor over all terms. I feel I may be missing something. The $\pm$ is there because I cannot remember whether the last sign was minus or plus.

**Is there some trick to factorize this or is this question vacuous? What does it mean to factorize this?**

Comment: You have to write as a product. Your attempt is the difference of two products.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thank you, how would you solve this $a^2-ab-bc+c^2$? Moment, have to think myself...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We observe that

\begin{eqnarray}
a^2-ab-bc+c^2&=&a^2+c^2-b(a+c)\\
&=&(a+c)^2-b(a+c)-2ac\\
&=&(a+c)^2-b(a+c)+\frac{b^2}{4}-\frac{b^2+8ac}{4}\\
&=&\left(a+c-\frac{b}{2}\right)^2-\frac{b^2+8ac}{4}.
\end{eqnarray}
Hence, if $b^2+8ac\geq 0$ then
$$
a^2-ab-bc+c^2=\left(a+c-\frac{b}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{b^2+8ac}{4}}\right)\left(a+c-\frac{b}{2}-\sqrt{\frac{b^2+8ac}{4}}\right)
$$

Comment: What about with arbitrary constants $A,B,C,D$ like $A a^2+B ab+ C bc+D C^2$? Is there any generic way to find the factorization? Anyway +1, very good thinking out of the box -- works even with complex numbers!

Answer (score 8):

$a^2-ab-bc-c^2=a^2-c^2-ab-bc=(a-c)(a+c)-b(a+c)=(a-c-b)(a+c)$.

If $a^2-ab-bc+c^2$ is factorizable, it is equal to $(\alpha a + \beta b + \gamma c)(\alpha' a + \beta' b + \gamma' c)$ where $\alpha,\alpha',\beta, \beta',\gamma, \gamma' \in \mathbb{R}$. So, $\alpha \alpha'=1$, $\gamma \gamma'=1$ and $\alpha \gamma' + \alpha' \gamma=0$.

$0=\alpha' \gamma( \alpha \gamma' + \alpha' \gamma)=(\alpha \alpha')(\gamma \gamma')+ (\alpha' \gamma)^2=1 +( \alpha' \gamma)^2$. It's impossible.

$a^2-ab-bc+c^2$ is not factorizable.

Comment: The moment you wrote it, I solved it also :D I realized this $a^2-c^2=(a-c)(a+c)$ and $ab+bc=b(a+c)$. Always when I need to speak/write something, things become easier! 9 mins to accept...

Comment: @hhh, 9 mins to accept...
Accepting an answer should be more a marathon than a sprint.

Comment: It is possible to factorize this if $a,b,c,\alpha,\alpha',\gamma,\gamma' \in \mathbb C$. Choose $\alpha '\gamma=i$ then $1+(\alpha'\gamma)^2=1-1=0$. Thinking now for complex numbers...anyway smart analysis +1!